# How to get precision when rotating / positioning textures?

Tags: uv, uv-image-editor, texture-coordinates

I am modeling a coin where heads and tails are the same image, and imported an image for the heads/tails faces.
I created a new **Emission** material for the faces, then gave it an **Image texture** and assigned it.

[image]

However, my image is slightly rotated:

[image]

So in the **UV/Image Editor** window, I rotated the face to align it vertically (<kbd>R</kbd>), I also scaled it a bit:

[image]

However, now that I would like to apply the same rotation / scaling values to the other face of the coin, I cannot find the **rotation values** that I just created anywhere.
Do these values get applied automatically? Are they written in one of the panels? And what about the scaling info?

*I couldn't find a similar question. [This](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/71521/cycles-mapping-node-rotation-pivot) is the opposite of what I want to do, since I am rotating in the Image editor for visual comfort, not in a Mapping node (therefore, even if I add Mapping Nodes, rotating the texture in the Image editor doesn't change the Mapping Nodes value).*

Answer (score 1):

Edit1:
For conveniance I build a Group-Node that does the centering, and also allows to plug in Rot_Vectors.
This was done by combining the help from:
    [Cycles mapping node - rotation pivot](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/71521/cycles-mapping-node-rotation-pivot/71538#71538)
    [How to add a socket for mapping node?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/93589/how-to-add-a-socket-for-mapping-node)
    [Can I make a custom node from a group and have that available in other projects?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7826/can-i-make-a-custom-node-from-a-group-and-have-that-available-in-other-projects)

This is how the node is used:
[image]

This is the inside of the node, with the Translate and Rotate node from gandalf3:
[image]

And here an optional Driver Setup to controll your rotation with an gameobject in the scene. Maby you could build yourselfe a GameObject that Visualizes your Rotation in the Viewport if you want to go further.
[image]

Edit_0:
If there are no other reasons you dont want to use a mapping node i would recomend the material view for visual comfort.

The reason you dont get any rotation value in a panel as you get in Object-Mode is that there are no objects, just verts in the u-v-coordinate system those are represented as vector2 -> u and v. Its the same in Edit-Mode, there the vers are also just points as Vector3. Rotation can be done as an operation but to store those blender oughta be node-based and also produce temporary objects of specifiec groups of verts that had been rotated.

I would recomend you to unwrap you upper and lower face together so they are exacly ontop each other and "rotated" the same and use a mapping node in Material View.

maby an option: orthogonal upsidedown camera to your coin and "Project from View" as unrwaping so your uv is axis-aligned

Comment: Hmm but if I unwrap both coin sides and apply the Dollar Sign texture, won't the Dollar Sign sign be reverse on one end? It needs to be legible on both sides. Also what if I place Mapping Nodes for the textured faces and *then* rotate it in the UV view? Would that create the values I'm looking for in the Mapping node? Otherwise is there another node I can use for rotation that makes more sense than Mapping? (i.e. one that allows to rotate from center...)

Comment: Rotate with MappingNode from center: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/71538/68710

Comment: No, when you rotate in UV-Editor there is no connection to mapping. Thats because you only rotate the selected verts there and not the hole thing as with the mapping node

Comment: Well, I think I don't rotate the verts, since they don't move in the 3D view, it rotates the image relatively to the verts (even though in the UV IMage Editor it's the verts that seem to move rather than the image... oddly enough). Your link is the one I refered to in the question, which is the one I say is I find very cumbersome...

Comment: Ah okay sry, found that one on my own :)

Comment: If i understand it correctly: in the UV-Editor you rotate the projection of the verts in the U-V Space, you just position them via the rotation to other individual coordinates between u:0-1, v:0-1, then in the mapping node you take the hole information as vector from the uv space and rotate that.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure I totally understand what gets transformed in the UV editor (vertices location in relation to the image?) and where this information is stored (it's definitely stored somewhere). There's mapping via the UV Image Editor window and then through the Nodes... this overlapping is weird. Maybe someone could make a node setup that makes placing image textures a little easier...?

Comment: check my updated answer at the top, its maby not the real easy placing texture solution but its one step less building the nodes, and via the driver option you got some kind of direct/visual controller in the 3D View.  had fun building it and already saved it in my node prests for further use, so thanks for the question :)