# Scale Texture preview in uv editor

Tags: uv, uv-image-editor, scale

I have changed a texture scale directly in the object material (with a mapping node). But now, the texture preview in the uv editor doesn't match the material texture mapping, because it is constrained by the 0-1 uv square. Is it possible to scale the uv editor texture preview without this constraint?

[image]

Ty

Comment: by scaling the uv input with a mapping node, the uv layout in the uv editor will not be changed. To reorganize your uv layout there you have to select the related faces in edit mode. Also this means that you dont scale the texture in the uv editor but you scale/reorgansie your projected faces within and above that 0-1 space.

Comment: Ty! i understand . The shader scales the uvs, not the texture. Is there a way to scale uvs on the object directly, with a modifier? I can do that in 3dsmax with the "uvw xform" modifier (non destructive workflow).

Comment: the only non-destructive way i know is the mapping node. if you want to scale from other pivots then bottom-left you could do it with a node setup: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/71436/68710  unfortunatly i dont know nothing else