# How to properly scale a texture from the bottom left in the compositor?

Tags: uv, node-editor, compositing-nodes, image, texture-coordinates

**My problem is as follows:**

- I need to scale and offset a texture by arbitrary amounts.
- I cannot find a meaningful relationship between scaling and offset on the texture node in the compositor to produce a texture that scales from the bottom left consistently.
- I also need to apply an additional (true) offset which should be trivial once the formula to offset it in such a way to begin scaling from the bottom left is found.

In this example, it looks incorrect from what I want, which is regular texture scaling from the bottom left. It is instead scaling from the center (curse whoever made the decision for it to function this way):

[image: Text]

In this example, it looks correct because I know you need to set the offset to 0.5 to compensate for the 2.0 scale:

[image: Text]

However, I cannot come up with a formula that will give me 0.5 from 2.0 and still work across an arbitrary range. For example, if the scale is 1.0, the offset needs to be 0.0. If the scale is 4.0 the offset needs to be 0.75. If the scale is 1.5 it needs to be 0.33(some small trailing number) and so on.

I know blender is unconventional in several areas but this area is particularly painful to deal with because there's no resources that I could find to address this issue other than the inverse of what I want which is also done on a material instead of inside the compositor that can be found here: [Keep texture centered while scaling](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/71426/keep-texture-centered-while-scaling) I tried to experiment with that solution and apply it to my situation but I was ultimately defeated and unable to come up with a way to make it work in my use case.